# How to find counts of distinct objects using Java streams

Tags: java, count, java-stream, distinct

I have a list of Thing objects:

```
class Thing {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

`List<Thing> lst` contains following;

```
[{'1', 'AB'},{'2', 'CD'},{'1', 'AB'},{'1','AB'},{'2','CD'},{'3','EF'}]
```

Now I want to use Java streams or any util functions to get a distinct count on id:
I want the output to be,

```
id   count
1    3
2    2 
3    1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13):

You can get it using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) the `id` attribute and then [`counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) its occurrences as:

```
List<Thing> objects = new ArrayList<>(); // initalise as in the question 
Map<String, Long> countForId = objects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Thing::getId, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I've read that for relatively small structures, a simple for loop can be faster than using streams.  Maybe this is something to consider, generally spraching.

Comment: @Adrian, in real time scenario, I will have many rows, thats the reason I wanted to go for streams

Answer (score 1):

one could also use the `toMap` collector:

```
lst.stream().collect(toMap(Thing::getId, v -> 1, Math::addExact));
```

creates a `Map<String, Integer>` where the `Thing::getId` is the key mapper used to select the map keys and `v -> 1` is the value mapper used to select the map values and in the case of a key collision we add the corresponding values with the merge function `Math::addExact`.

or Map::merge:

```
Map<String, Integer> accumulator = new HashMap<>();
lst.forEach(t -> accumulator.merge(t.getId(), 1, Math::addExact));
```

Same idea as above, if the `Thing::getId` is already present in the `accumulator` map, we merge them with `Math::addExact` otherwise we accumulate the provided key and value into the map.

if the order matters as shown in your post, then instead of `HashMap` above, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`.

You could also provide a map into which the elements are to be accumulated into to preserve order in the `toMap` collector with:

```
lst.stream().collect(toMap(Thing::getId, v -> 1, Math::addExact, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

or using the `groupingBy` collector:

```
lst.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Thing::getId, 
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.counting()));
```